# Какое определяемое слово пропущено?

Tags: числительные

Учителя на доске пишут, например, "первое января, двадцать четвёртое сентября" и т.п. Интересно, порядковые числительные всегда в среднем роде. С каким определяемым словом они согласуются?

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, определяемым словом является "число"

Comment: Ну, да.Число какое? Первое.